# How to unbind an array copy in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am trying to copy one array to another and use this like the new array without any changes to old one:

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label>Test input</label>
       <input v-model="testArray[0].name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Input">
    </div>
    <br>
    <pre>testArray: {{ testArray[0] | json}}</pre>
    <pre>templateArray: {{ templateArray[0] | json  }}</pre>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
      testArray: [],
      templateArray: [{name: "TEST"},], 
  },
  ready: function() {
      this.testArray = this.templateArray.slice(0);
    },
});
```

the issue is that then I am updating new array 'testArray' I also change old array 'templateArray'.

The script in action: https://jsfiddle.net/4po1cpkp/7/

Is there any way to create new array based on array template without directly binding it to template?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As Vue.js documentation says:

> Under the hood, Vue.js attaches a hidden property `__ob__` and
>   **recursively** converts the object’s enumerable properties into getters
>   and setters to enable dependency collection. Properties with keys that
>   starts with $ or _ are skipped.

You can store your template array with name started from underscore sign:

```
  data: {
      testArray: [],
      _templateArray: [{ name: "TEST" }]
  },
  ready: function() {
      this.testArray = this.$data._templateArray;
  }
```

Or you if need it as a Vue.js object:

```
this.testArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.templateArray));
```

The second case might be slow for big data.

Answer (score 0):

I used Vue extend function Vue.util.extend to copy array with un-binding in Vue 2:

```
this.items_list.push(Vue.util.extend({}, this.list_item));
```

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1**

You should assign data to testArray by using JavaScript concat() function to copy old array to new array like this one, use this if you work with small array data:

```
this.testArray = [].concat(this.templateArray);
```

**OPTION 2**

You can use ES6 spread operator to merge multiple array like this:

```
this.testArray = [...[],...this.templateArray]
```

**OPTION 3 ( For big data )**

```
const MAX_BLOCK_SIZE = 65535; // max parameter array size for use in Webkit
export function appendArrayInPlace(dest: [], source: []) {
    let offset = 0;
    let itemsLeft = source.length;

    if (itemsLeft <= MAX_BLOCK_SIZE) {
        dest.push.apply(dest, source);
    } else {
        while (itemsLeft > 0) {
            const pushCount = Math.min(MAX_BLOCK_SIZE, itemsLeft);
            const subSource = source.slice(offset, offset + pushCount);
            dest.push.apply(dest, subSource);
            itemsLeft -= pushCount;
            offset += pushCount;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

OPTION 3 CREDIT TO [enter link description here](https://twitter.com/zenmumbler)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `slice()` of array prototype read more in [MDN Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

`this.testArray = [].slice.call(this.templateArray)`

Comment: `this.testArray = this.templateArray.slice()` seems to do the exact same thing.

Comment: If it's the same as `slice()` it doesn't work for what the OP asked. It'll continue to be deeply attached to the original array, as mentioned in the question.