# vue merge two arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 components:

1. parent component (vue-bootstrap modal with a vue-bootstrap table)
2. child component (vue-bootstrap modal with a form)

When I submit the form in the child component I want to push the object to the parent table array and that works! But when I reset the form it also resets the object in the table array and I don't know why. I tried `push` and `concat`.

parent variable:

```js
MA02_E_tb // table array [{descr_forn: '',fornitore:'',n_oda:''},{descr_forn: '',fornitore:'',n_oda:''}]
```

```
 data() {
      return {
        form: {
          descr_forn: 'prova',
          fornitore:'prova',
          n_oda:'prova',
      }
    },
  methods: {
      resetModal() {
        this.form.descr_forn = '',
        this.form.fornitore = '',
        this.form.n_oda = '',
      },
      onSubmit: function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        this.$parent.MA02_E_tb = this.$parent.MA02_E_tb.concat(this.form)
      },
```

result:

```js
MA02_E_tb = [{descr_forn: 'prova',fornitore:'prova',n_oda:'prova'}]
```

When I reopen the child modal and I reset the object form with the `resetModal` method the result is:

```js
MA02_E_tb = [{descr_forn: '',fornitore:'',n_oda:''}]
form = [{descr_forn: '',fornitore:'',n_oda:''}]
```

Why does it reset `MA02_E_tb` if it's another variable?

Comment: maybe this may help you through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344041/how-to-unbind-an-array-copy-in-vue-js

Comment: your parent variable `MA02_E_tb `  point to `form` and this is by reference. So if you change form it will also change all variable that are point to it

Comment: Better you can emit event from child component and update your parent based on event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, you really, really, really shouldn't be using `$parent` like that. You should be emitting an event instead. But that isn't what's causing the problem.

The actual problem is that you are passing an object by reference. If you then change that object it will be changed in both places. It doesn't matter what name, identifier or path you use to access it, it's still the same object.

Assuming it is a flat object you can make a shallow copy using the spread operator, `...`:

```js
this.$parent.MA02_E_tb = this.$parent.MA02_E_tb.concat({...this.form})
```

This will create a new object with the same properties as `this.form`. It is important to realise that this is only a shallow copy. If `this.form` contained further reference types (i.e. objects, arrays, etc.) then those may need copying as well.

As an event this would be something like:

```js
this.$emit('submit', {...this.form})
```

You'd then need a suitable `@submit` listener in the parent template to update the array. The idea here is that only the owner of the data should be allowed to modify it and in this case that array is owned by the parent.

Comment: using this.$emit('submit', {...this.form}) work perfectly